# Pass method expression attribute through to nested composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, composite-component

I have composite component `DocumentSelector`, which contains another composite component `modalWindow`.

```
<cc:interface componentType="selector.DocumentSelector">
     <cc:attribute name="showSelector"
              method-signature="void listener(java.util.List)"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <ccs:modalWindow id="modal_window" showListener="#{cc.showSelector}"
                     mode="ajax">

        </ccs:modalWindow>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

I need to pass method `#{cc.showSelector}` to composite component `modalWindow` from faces component `DocumentSelector`. But I have `PropertyNotFoundException`
because `ElResolver` associate `#{cc}` with `modalWindow` component instead of `DocumentSelector`

modalWindow component:

```
<cc:interface componentType="statistics.ModalWindow">
    <cc:attribute name="showListener" method-signature="void show()"/>
    <cc:attribute name="hideListener" method-signature="void hide()"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
</cc:implementation>
```

I use Java EE 7, JSF 2.2, WildFly 8.2.0

Answer (score 5):

Use `<cc:attribute targets>` to basically move the attribute to the specified component and use if necessary `<cc:attribute targetAttributeName>` to rename it.

```
<cc:attribute ... targets="modal_window" targetAttributeName="showListener" />
```

Don't forget to remove the `showListener="#{cc.showSelector}"`.

Comment: I try to use `<cc:attribute targets>`, but it not works in my composite component. `getAttributes().get("showListener")` return `null`.

Comment: It isn't a value expression. It's a method expression.